# How to record grease pencil sketching in real-time and retain editability

Tags: keyframes, grease-pencil, draw-mode

I am looking for a way to capture real-time drawing in Grease Pencil.

For example, to make a video like this https://youtu.be/tfF_-Db8iSA?t=36 of drawing math on a virtual whiteboard while speaking, but be able to use Grease Pencil Edit/Sculpt features for post-processing to tidy up the strokes. The end result would be the seemingly real-time video of speaking and drawing at the same time but with cleaner strokes.

I have found a workflow that is close to what I want:

1. Enable *Auto Keying* to record strokes appearing at the right wall-clock time.
2. Enable *Additive Drawing* so that each frame includes the previous strokes.
3. Enable *Build Modifier* in *Additive* mode to animate only the new stroke.

This successfully animates the strokes appearing one-by-one and *starting* at the right time. The problem is that they don't *finish* at the right time. Specifically if there is a pause between strokes then the first one is slowed down to finish when the second one starts. But what I want is to preserve the original timing of both the start *and* end of the stroke.

Mechanically the issue seems to be that *Auto Keying* is creating a new keyframe at the start of each drawing command, when I click left-mouse, but it does not create one at the end of each drawing command, when I release left-mouse.

I would love some advice on whether it is possible to accomplish what I want, or else whether the existing behavior of auto keying is intentional and desirable, and even tips on how the code might be modified to support the feature that I want.

Note: I have tested with Blender 3.3 (on Linux.)

Comment: If the problem is only pausing, you can animate the Factor property of the build modifier.

Comment: Can this be handled by "Auto Keying" somehow? It's vital that the start/end times are automatically recorded when the strokes are made because going in later and manually "inventing" end times for the strokes would seem a lot of work.

Comment: I realize now that there is a major flaw in my workflow: editing/sculpting strokes won't work because the changes won't carry through to the copies of those strokes made by Additive Editing.

So it starts to sound like what I need is to have one frame covering the entire animation and then to animate the Factor property so that strokes appear at the wall-clock appropriate moments.